# automatically infer class name as T for generics

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        new Logger<TestClass1>().Log(LogType.Info, "FROM TESTCLASS1.TESTMETHOD1");
    }
}
```

When instantiating **Logger** and passing in **TestClass1** as **generic T**, there could be a problem if the developer types in some thing else as opposed to TestClass1. For example, following line of code could be an **issue**.

```
new Logger<Test123>().Log(LogType.Info, "FROM TESTCLASS1.TESTMETHOD1");
```

How can I write the following line of code that it would automatically infer **TestClass1** and pass it?

```
new Logger<TestClass1>().Log(LogType.Info, "FROM TESTCLASS1.TESTMETHOD1");
```

I have tried the following 2 lines of code but no luck.

```
new Logger<this>().Log(LogType.Info, "FROM TESTCLASS1.TESTMETHOD1");
new Logger<this.GetType>().Log(LogType.Info, "FROM TESTCLASS1.TESTMETHOD1");
```

**UPDATE**
Through out my application, I could be passing in any class whats so ever such as TestClass1, MyClass123 etc. etc.  so I may not be able to put any generic constraints.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about an extension method:

```
public static Logger<T> GetLogger<T>(this T obj)
{
    return new Logger<T>();
}
```

so you can

```
this.GetLogger()
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a generic type constraint? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is the time to make a private property.  Then, you can have your devs do `this.Logger.Log(blah)`

```
private Logger Logger {
   get {
      return new Logger<TestClass1>();
   }
}
```